# Understand heroku's log

Tags: heroku, facebook-messenger-bot

Can someone explain me the different lines in this piece of Heroku's log while my Facebook Messenger bot is running (and people interacting)

```
2018-08-19T12:21:53.976999+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.124.6.113 - - [19/Aug/2018:12:21:53 +0000] "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "facebookexternalua"
2018-08-19T12:21:54.060862+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.8.0.31 - - [19/Aug/2018:12:21:54 +0000] "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "facebookexternalua"
2018-08-19T12:21:53.977357+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/webhook" host=some-app.herokuapp.com request_id=9691c0bc-43c7-4a5e-83c1-c636a4cc2789 fwd="31.13.115.9" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=462ms status=200 bytes=161 protocol=https
2018-08-19T12:21:54.062745+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/webhook" host=some-app.herokuapp.com request_id=624ca87a-b237-4a16-9e74-ad086c776d2a fwd="31.13.115.11" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=514ms status=200 bytes=161 protocol=https
2018-08-19T12:21:55.013052+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.127.18.55 - - [19/Aug/2018:12:21:55 +0000] "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "facebookexternalua"
2018-08-19T12:21:55.012197+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/webhook" host=some-app.herokuapp.com request_id=032fef2b-5029-4a7b-903c-45b685b0a9ef fwd="31.13.115.2" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=464ms status=200 bytes=161 protocol=https
2018-08-19T12:21:56.138658+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.10.128.18 - - [19/Aug/2018:12:21:56 +0000] "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "facebookexternalua"
2018-08-19T12:21:56.137932+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/webhook" host=some-app.herokuapp.com request_id=7f32d132-5587-4cfb-9dd4-b44ddeb8b684 fwd="31.13.115.13" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=734ms status=200 bytes=161 protocol=https
```

In fact, I would like to know what are the times of the type "service = 734ms"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`service` might be the time in milliseconds, in between receiving the request and serving the response; measured at the `router` and not the web `dyno`, where the request is being forwarded to.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku's documentation for their router log format is [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#heroku-router-log-format). Here's what they say about "service":

> amount of time in milliseconds spent proxying data between the backend web process and the client

In other words, it's the amount of time it's taking your app (the backend web process) to process the request.

Comment: my guess was not that bad, when comparing guess vs. the documentation.